# Adding environment variable to React project

Tags: reactjs, npm, environment-variables

I am trying to add a .env file with the text "SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true" but I'm not exactly sure how to go about this. Can someone please help me out with this?

PS: I'm a complete beginner to React development, npm and everything else.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `.env` file contents is fine - but your file isn't actually named `.env` - you have file-extensions disabled so you can't see that it's real name is `.env.txt`. You need to remove the `.txt` part.

Change your explorer settings to file all file extensions and then remove it using F2.

Comment: How do I change my explorer settings? Can you please be more specific? Should I change my explorer settings in the text file, or in the project directory?

Comment: Start > Control Panel > File Explorer Options > View >  Uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types" - or use a terminal window to rename the files.

Comment: Too circuitous. The other method was better. Thanks, anyhow!